# ruby on rails - First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am geting **ArgumentError in Catagorys#create**
**First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty**
And it happens if i add to model validate

My Catagorys controler

```
Class CatagorysController < ApplicationController
layout "admin_login_registration"
def index
@Catagorys = Kategorija.all
end

def new
 @category_new = Kategorija.new
end

  def create
      @new_catagory = Kategorija.new(catagory_params)

      if @new_catagory.save

        redirect_to catagorys_path
      else
        render action: "new"
      end
      end

      def delete
      end

      def update
      end

      def catagory_params
       params.require(:kategorija).permit(:kategorija , :description)
      end
      end
```

And my new.htm.erb

```
 <%= form_for (@category_new) do |f| %>
  <% if @category_new.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% for message in @category_new.errors.full_messages %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<p>  Kategorijas nosaukums: <%= f.text_field :kategorija %></p>
<p>  Apraksts:   <%= f.text_area_tag :description, nil,class: "col-lg-2 control-label" %></p>
<p><%= f.submit "Izveidot kategoriju", class: "login login-submit" %></p>
```

And the last one katagorija model

```
class Kategorija < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :kategorija, presence: true
end
```

**How to fix it?**

Comment: A few advices: 1. Don't put spaces between method call and parameters if you use `()`: `form_for(@category_new)` instead of `form_for (@category_new)`. 2. Use English variable/classes/tables names. `Category` instead of `Kategorija`.

Comment: clearly `@category_new` is not available, if you <%= raise `@category_new.inspect` %> you will be getting nil, One way to solve would be to write Catagory.new in the form_for, But with this kind of multi-lingual code, its hard to say the actual cause of error.
Plus remove the `space` between form_for & (

Comment: Sorry about that i do not use English syntax, I found a bug elsewhere,it shows now that i dont have the right rout to it , i will try to correct it.

Comment: @Trusislv1 it's because, as I wrote in my answer, you named your controller incorrectly. It should be named `CategoriesController`, and in your `routes.rb` you should have `resources :categories`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your error because you expect `@category_new` variable in form, while you define `@new_category` variable in `create` action. What you should do is unify these names, I suggest using simply `@category` in both cases:

```
def new
  @category = Category.new
end

def create
  @category = Category.new(category_params)
  if @category.save
    redirect_to :categories
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

and in form:

```
<%= form_for(@category) do |f| %>
```

My answer, of course, includes naming convention that I **strongly** recommend you to use. And BTW in English, pluralized form of 'category' is 'categories', so your controller should be named `CategoriesController`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the problem was the names because they were not the same :)